# In what continuity does Joker want his "g** d*** electric car"?

Tags: dc, batman, episode-identification

I came across [this video clip](https://ifunny.co/video/where-is-my-god-dam-electric-car-bruce-joker-x8s07RMu7) where Scarecrow and Joker have captured Batman and are going to interrogate him and Scarecrow takes his mask off:

> [Joker] WHAT!!?
>
> [Scarecrow] Bloody hell, it's billionaire playboy Bruce Wayne!
>
> [Joker] No! No! Are you shitting me! What is wrong with you? Don't you think I would have done that had I wanted to? Half the fun of our relationship was the mystery. Now I know Batman is just some boring rich asshole with parental issues.
>
> [Batman] That's really reductive.
>
> [Joker] Thanks for ruining the funnest thing I had going. Now I don't even feel like torturing him.
>
> [Scarecrow] Sorry. I thought it be the kind of thing Harley would do.
>
> [Joker] I don't care about Harley!
>
> [Scarecrow] I'm sorry, look, I musta misread the situation when you kept saying her name and reminiscing about all your memories together. Over and over and over and...
>
> *Joker melts Scarecrow's face off with chemicals*
>
> [Joker] Not even that was fun.
>
> [Joker *walks up to Batman*] Wayne Tech promised an electric car by this year. I put a deposit down. WHERE'S MY GODDAMN ELECTRIC CAR, BRUCE!

Now there is a lot to unpack here for me; all the swearing, the graphic destruction of Scarecrow, Bruce possibly being an Elon Musk stand-in...

Does this come from new Batman show, or possibly some internet meme? With all the ways content is produced and distributed these I am not sure and would like to know more context.

Comment: The tags on the video indicate it's from the [*Harley Quinn*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harley_Quinn_(TV_series)) show.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kl0-vMpzMrg

Comment: Wait wait wait... Batman is Bruce Wayne?   How about a spoiler tag next time.

Comment: "all the swearing" seems to be vastly overstating the case. None of this seems to constitute swearing to me as a Brit (although I guess goddamn is almost there)

Comment: Where else but Harley Quinn do you get that much swearing? :D

Comment: @Tristan shitting doesn't do it for you? That's one of the words here is the US that can't be said on radio or regular cable channels.  Maybe "all" was exaggerating a little though...

Comment: hah! Somehow managed to completely miss that, you're entirely right, please ignore

Comment: @Skooba: Strictly speaking, in the US you can show almost anything you want on cable. In practice it's messier than that, because you have to convince the producers, the network, etc. that it won't cause massive PR fallout, but the government mostly doesn't give a crap.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This clip comes from the HBO Max Series **[Harley Quinn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kl0-vMpzMrg)** (2019-). The episode is titled "[The Final Joke](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt11632580/?ref_=tt_ch)" (S01E13) and first aired 2020-02-21.

> Ivy is dead, Harley's crew is captured, and Batman is his captive. Joker has everything he's ever wanted - but is it enough without Harley at his side?